# Rails Web services for Android App and Data caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am new in rails development. My requirement is to make a web service for Android App and store data for future use.
My database will occasionally update so i need store my data in any other table so that any future Web Service call will happen then its first check whether data is updated by comparing stored data.
If not it will Serve the stored data. Otherwise It will return the updated data.

**See I already mention that i an new in rails development so please help me as beginner and please ignore my English if anything wrong**

Comment: I think this question is a bit to general. You can easily store, update, delete or read data from a table with Rails as an API. What is your exact question?

Comment: How i can check that this data is updated or not??

Comment: If i'm not get you wrong, you want  your databse seprate from your rails webservice.

Comment: @KhAmmad I need to store data for future use.. so 4r dat can i use separate table where i can store or what i need to do??

Comment: future use by this api or any other api ?

Comment: @KhAmmad by the same API

Comment: If you have an existing table, you can use that one too... or create a new one, you can go both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Please watch this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem) to get idea how to develop rails-api:

In the your rails app, you will have different actions like:

**index:** get all the record

**Show:**  get specific record

**Create:** create new record in the database

**Update:** Update the existing record

Hopefully, this will give you the rough idea how things will happen